# Instructions are recognized as labels with NASM's %use masm feature

Tags: assembly, nasm

I wrote this assembly code.

```
%use masm
global _start
section .data

realarray dq 0x1
     dq 0x2
     dq 0x3
     dq 0x4
section .text
_start:
    mov rsi, 0x5
    mov rdi, realarray
    mov rax, 0x0
    mov rcx, 0x1
loop:
    cmp rcx, rsi
    jg end
    add rax, qword ptr [rdi+8*rcx]  
    add rcx, 0x1
    jmp loop
end: 
    nop
    nop
```

so, I compiled the code.

```
nasm -felf64 -O0 code.asm
ld code.o
```

but, It became an unintended executable file.
following, dis assemble of exe file

```
$objdump -d -M intel a.out       

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:   48 be 05 00 00 00 00    movabs rsi,0x5
  401007:   00 00 00 
  40100a:   48 bf 00 20 40 00 00    movabs rdi,0x402000
  401011:   00 00 00 
  401014:   48 b8 00 00 00 00 00    movabs rax,0x0
  40101b:   00 00 00 
  40101e:   48 b9 01 00 00 00 00    movabs rcx,0x1
  401025:   00 00 00 

0000000000401028 <loop>:
  401028:   48 39 f1                cmp    rcx,rsi

000000000040102b <jg>:
  40102b:   48 03 04 cf             add    rax,QWORD PTR [rdi+rcx*8]
  40102f:   48 81 c1 01 00 00 00    add    rcx,0x1
  401036:   e9 ed ff ff ff          jmp    401028 <loop>
  40103b:   90                      nop
  40103c:   90                      nop
```

**Why is the `jg end` instruction recognized as a label?**
Also, why is the jump instruction acting strangely?

Please say what further information you need.

Comment: `label end` or `label ends` seems to be a MASMism that seems to be partially supported when you specify `%use masm`. Rename the `end` label to eg `_end`.

Comment: IDK what you mean by "jump acting strangely", other than `jmp` having a wastefully long encoding because you used `nasm -O0`.  It seems significant that `end:` was *not* recognized as a label; probably `%use masm` defines `end` at the empty string.

Comment: I'd have expected a warning about the "orphan" label, `jg` with no operand being treated as a label.  You can see from the objdump output that there's a `jg` label there where the instruction should have been.  `-w+label-orphan` aka `-Worphan-labels` is on by default, warning about a word without a `:` getting treated as a label.  (That's why `loop` can work as a label name even though it's the mnemonic for an x86 instruction).  But I tried this on my machine with NASM 2.15.05 and there is indeed no warning.

Comment: As @ecm said, this probably wouldn't be valid in MASM due to using `end` as a label name.  So don't `%use masm` if you don't want to avoid MASM keywords.

Comment: @PeterCordes The label orphan warning is only used when there is no other macro or keyword or instruction after a label, **and** it doesn't have a colon.

Answer (score 3):

- As per [documentation of MASM compatibility support](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5) (NASM version 2.15.05):

  > The `END` directive is ignored.

  Since NASM is open-source, you can easily verify this:
  [`end` is a dummy macro](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/blob/nasm-2.15.xx/macros/masm.mac#L76-L78).
  Therefore the line

  ```
      jg end
  ```

  is indeed correctly simply declaring a label `jg`.
- An orphan label warning is not triggered because the preprocessor (while expanding `end` macro) emits a *normalized* LOC.
  If you call

  ```bash
  nasm ‑E code.asm
  ```

  (meaning preprocess only) you’ll see the a. m. line is expanded to

  ```
  jg :
  %line 17+0 code.asm

  %line 18+1 code.asm
  ```

  An orphan label warning would be triggered if there was a label *without* a trailing colon.
- The *quick and dirty* solution is to simply

  ```
  %unimacro end 0+
  ```

  after `%use masm` and before the first occurrence of `end`.
- Like [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73402181/instructions-are-recognized-as-labels-with-nasms-use-masm-feature#comment129643818_73402181) I don’t know what’s meant by

  > […] jump instruction acting strangely […]

  The [documentation of `-O0`](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.1) clearly says

  > `‑O0`:
  > No optimization.
  > All operands take their long forms, if a short form is not specified, except conditional jumps.

  so the long encoding should be expected.